# Parse model from data object

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

My API returns a response that looks like this:

```
{
    status: number,
    message?: string,
    data?: T,
}
```

So in a retrofit service I have to wrap all return values in this response class:

```
data class Response<T>(val status: Int, val message: String?, val data: T?)

interface MyService {
    @GET("user")
    suspend fun getUser(id: String): Response<User>
}
```

Now the question: How can make it return a class without wrapping a return value?

```
suspend fun getUser(id: String): User
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are making the interface you'll have to make multiple functions return multiple return objects.
Try Making a Generic Response interface and then Handle the response in your code. Make your interface like this :

```
@GET
suspend fun getUser(@Url endpoint: String,id: String): Call<ResponseBody>
```

Then in your Response Function Use it like :

```
override fun onResponse(call : Call<ResponseBody>,response: Response<ResponseBody>) {
        //Parse your object here
        String responseBody = response.body().string();
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(responseBody);
        val responseObject : User = Gson().fromJson(
                    json.optJSONObject("data")?.toString(),
                    User::class.java)
    }
```

make sure to implement Gson in your app gradle.

Answer (score 0):

You can adapt return types using Retrofit's [`CallAdapter`](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/CallAdapter.html) and [`CallAdapter.Factory`](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/CallAdapter.Factory.html). Knowing this should help you find some code examples online, which you can adapt to your specific use case.